# Excluir Diretório via Git Bash - Erro: Device or resource busy

Tags: git

Estou tentando excluir um diretório via Git Bash, porém, está dando o erro **"Device or resource busy"**, conforme print abaixo. Não localizei qualquer aplicativo que esteja ocupando este Diretório. Existe algum comando para que eu possa "forçar" a remoção do mesmo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use `rm -rf <nome da pasta>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para forçar a remoção de um diretório/pasta use:

```
rm --recursive -f [diretório]
```

Onde:

- f: força a remoção
- recusive: irá buscar os arquivos abaixo do diretório passado como parâmetro

Para saber mais sobre o comando:

```
rm --help
```